# MetroFramework in VB 2013, certain controls don't appear on form

Tags: vb.net, user-interface, microsoft-metro, controls

I installed the MetroFramework in VB 2013 via NuGet and I have it working partially. Some of the controls will not appear on the form:

MetroTile, MetroTextBox, MetroTabControl, MetroStyleManager, MetroCheckBox, MetroLabel, MetroProgressBar, MetroScrollBar, MetroRadioButton, MetroProgressSpinner, MetroButton

If I drag and drop a control onto the Form, its control will not appear... a gray box appears at the bottom of the design view. Then that control I attempted to put on the Form appears in the gray box with a small icon and its name by it. If you double click on the control in the gray box, it will open the Form.vb events/objects, but it will not initialize an event for that control.

There is not a lot of info on the net for the MetroFramework, and nothing in relation to my problem.

How do I make those controls appear on the form?

And, what exactly is that gray box on the bottom with the non-viewable controls? I have never seen it before.

Comment: The gray box is for controls with no on-form UI, like timers, dialog generators, and so forth. It's been around since VS 2003 I think.

Answer (score 1):

In the Manage Nuget Packages dialog, there are three or 4 versions of the Metroframework... download the one by Dennis Magno only; it will have a date of 9/16/14 ... it works the best. I'm using VS 2013, .NET 4.5

Answer (score 0):

You should add design.dll to your references.