# Not able to drop toolbox items into the window form?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

In my visual studio 2010. I am creating simple login window form in C#.And I am using the metro framework.Also I am new to visual studio.
I have referenced MetroFramework.dll.

So I am not able drag n drop the toolbox items into the window form, instead the toolbox items are going to the gray area below the window form,you can see in the screenshot below:

[image]

[image]
Code of Form1 and Form2 for reference.

so please tell me how to resolve this issue ,or what's the problem.
Thankyou.

Comment: is there something special about metroforms?

Comment: no , i just wanted to use a different UI and i found its vidio on youtube

Comment: you might want to ask that developer as it looks like they have a custom designer.  are you dragging it on to the form visual and now that bucket?

Comment: ya, I am dragging on to the window form and dropping it but it automatically comes to the grey colored area.

Comment: Are you referencing the MetroFramework DLL as well?

Comment: yes I have referenced it.

Comment: Is your code behind Form2 using MetroForm instead of Form? Public Partial Class Form2 : MetroForm

Comment: Yes, i am using  MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm instead of Form.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MetroFramework in VB 2013, certain controls don't appear on form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29129857/metroframework-in-vb-2013-certain-controls-dont-appear-on-form)

Comment: Thanks, all and  #Ethilium problem solved. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43160829/3703534